# Create a custom list in Swing Java

Tags: java, swing, media-player, jlabel

I want to create a custom list using JLabels in Swing. (Much like VLC playlist). The reason I chose JLabels instead of a JTable or List is that it allows more customizing like imageIcons easily.

But now I have a problem. I want to be able to move the labels up and down by dragging(Changing the row order). The JLables are in a boxlayout to be viewed as a list. Can someone help me with this?
Can I repaint the jPanel after setting the locations of Jlabels?

```
public class playListPanel extends JPanel {
private mediaList mdList;
private JPanel base;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private boolean locked = false;
private JLabel lockedlb ;
public playListPanel(mediaList mdList){


    this.mdList = mdList;
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      init();  
     this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
         public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt){
               if(locked){
                lockedlb.setLocation(evt.getPoint());
                base.repaint();
               }
            }
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt){
               lockedlb.setLocation(evt.getPoint());
               base.repaint();

            }
            public void mouseRelease(MouseEvent evt){
               if(locked){
               int y = evt.getY();
               int n = y%20;
               mediaList temp = (mediaList) mdList.copy();
               temp.remove(Integer.getInteger(lockedlb.getName())-1);
                 temp.insert(mdList.get(Integer.getInteger(lockedlb.getName())-1),n);
               mdList.set(temp);
               init();
               base.repaint();
               locked = true;
               }else{
               } 
            }

    });
}

public void init(){
     base = new JPanel();
    base.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,0));
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(base);

    base.setLayout(new BoxLayout(base,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    int i= 0;
    for(Object m : this.mdList){
        i = i+1;
        media temp = (media)m;
        JLabel label = new JLabel(" "+ temp.getMediaTitle());
        label.setName("" +i);
        label.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(label.getPreferredSize().width,label.getPreferredSize().height+4 ));
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt){
                locked =true;
                lockedlb = label;
                //label.setLocation(evt.getPoint());
            }

            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt){
               if(locked){
                lockedlb.setLocation(evt.getPoint());
                base.repaint();
               }
            }
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt){
               lockedlb.setLocation(evt.getPoint());
               base.repaint();

            }
            public void mouseRelease(MouseEvent evt){
               if(locked){
               int y = evt.getY();
               int n = y%20;
               mediaList temp = (mediaList) mdList.copy();
               temp.remove(Integer.getInteger(lockedlb.getName())-1);
               temp.insert(mdList.get(Integer.getInteger(lockedlb.getName())-1),n);
               mdList = temp;
               init();
               base.repaint();
               locked = true;
               }else{
               }
               }

        }
        );
        base.add(label);
        this.add(base,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Code... post the code!!

Comment: `"The reason I chose JLabels instead of a JTable or List is that it allows more customizing like imageIcons easily."` -- and this is the very reason why I would not choose JLabels. JTables and especially JLists can handle ImageIcons very well and are a lot easier to implement then your hand code JLabel construct.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you. I checked JList and found that it would use A CellRenderer to use images? Anyway I implemented it and it worked well so far.

Comment: It would SO much easier to achieve this with a `JList`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `BoxLayout` so `setLocation()` will not work for you. As @HovercraftFullOfEels said; `JList` supports image icons. You can design very custom lists with writing a `ListCellRenderer`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16591678/971067) is a good example of `JList` with custom renderers and drag&drop support. It can be a guide for you.